# How to resize polygon drawn on Google map in Android?

Tags: android

After searching lot I found the solution to draw the polygon by free hand on google map in android.

Now I want to resize that polygon by dragging it on a map, but I don't know how to do that.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
PolygonOptions rectOptions;
Polygon shape;  
private bool Is_MAP_Moveable = false; 
// to detect map is movable
// on create


FrameLayout fram_map = (FrameLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.fram_map);
Button btn_draw_State = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btn_draw_State);

if (btn_draw_State != null)
            {
                btn_draw_State.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (!Is_MAP_Moveable)
                    {
                        Is_MAP_Moveable = true;
                        fram_map.SetOnTouchListener(this);

                    }
                    else if (Is_MAP_Moveable)
                    {
                        Is_MAP_Moveable = false;
                    }
                } ;
            }


List<LatLng> val = new List<LatLng>();
public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{

        float x = e.GetX();
        float y = e.GetY();

        int x_co = (int)Math.Round(x);
        int y_co = (int)Math.Round(y);

        Projection p = mMap.Projection;
        Point x_y_points = new Point(x_co, y_co);

        LatLng latLng = mMap.Projection.FromScreenLocation(x_y_points);
        var latitude = latLng.Latitude;

        var longitude = latLng.Longitude;
        int eventaction = (int)e.Action;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                        // finger touches the screen
                        val.Add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
                        break;

                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                        // finger moves on the screen
                        val.Add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
                        break;

                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                        // finger leaves the screen
                        DrawMap();
                        break;
        }
        if (Is_MAP_Moveable == true)
        {
                return true;

        }
        else
        {
                return false;
        }

}

private void DrawMap()
{
        rectOptions = new PolygonOptions();
        foreach(var item in val)
        {
                rectOptions.Add(item);
        }
        rectOptions.InvokeFillColor(int.Parse("33ff0000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        rectOptions.InvokeStrokeColor(int.Parse("FF33A02C", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        rectOptions.InvokeStrokeWidth(3);
        rectOptions.Clickable(true);
        shape = mMap.AddPolygon(rectOptions);



}
```

Comment: Show us the code you are using to draw the polygon please.

Comment: @ Mohammed Bakr SikalThanks to took look .... please suggests if you know solution

Comment: Your setOnTouchListener code as well please.